# How to send the touch events of UIScrollView to the view behind it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uikit

i have a transparent UIScrollView on top of another view.

the scroll view has content - text and images, used to display info.

the view behind it has some images that the user should be able to tap on.
and the content over them is scrollable using the mentioned scrollview.

i want to be able to normally use the scroll view (no zoom though), but when that scroll view is not actually scrolling to let the tap events through to the view behind it.

using a combination of the touch and scroll events i can determine when to let the taps through.
but the view behind it still it does not receive them.

i have tried using something like this for all touch events:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    NSLog(@"touchesBegan %@", (_isScrolling ? @"YES" : @"NO"));

    if(!_isScrolling) 
    {
        NSLog(@"sending");
        [self.viewBehind touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    }
}
```

but it does not work.

also in my case i cannot really apply the hitTest and pointInside solutions, given the use case that i have.

Comment: Perhaps you can utilize locationInView in this case. But looking at your code, I'm not entirely sure what you want to do... Do you want any tap to result in the same outcome? Or do you want certain taps on certain images to do certain things? As of now, calling touchesBegan within touchesBegan makes no sense.

Comment: And could you post the code for your tap gesture recognizer?

Comment: to summaries what i want to do: if(!scroll) let the taps through :) i do not have a gesture recognizer... do i need one?

Comment: 100%. You need to add a UITapGestureRecognizer to the UIScrollView because it can only inherently recognize panning and pinching gestures.

Comment: ok Lyndsey, let me look into that and i will come back

Comment: "also in my case i cannot really apply the hitTest and pointInside solutions, given the use case that i have." care to explain? ;) seems like a pretty bold statement

Comment: i basically need the scrollview to scroll normally and when it does not scroll to let the tap through. both hittest or pointinside need to have clear areas where the tap should go through ... which is not the case :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First off `UIScrollView`s only inherently recognize `UIPanGestureRecognizer`s and `UIPinchGestureRecognizer`s so you need to add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the `UIScrollView` so it can recognize any tapping gestures as well:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];

// To prevent the pan gesture of the UIScrollView from swallowing up the
// touch event
tap.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;

[scrollView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

Then once you receive that tap gesture and the `handleTap:` action is triggered, you can use `locationInView:` to detect whether the tap gesture's position is in fact within the frame of one of the images below your scroll view, for example:

```
- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    // First get the tap gesture recognizers's location in the entire 
    // view's window
    CGPoint tapPoint = [recognizer locationInView:self.view];

    // Then see if it falls within one of your below images' frames
    for (UIImageView* image in relevantImages) {

        // If the image's coordinate system isn't already equivalent to
        // self.view, convert it so it has the same coordinate system
        // as the tap.
        CGRect imageFrameInSuperview = [image.superview convertRect:image toView:self.view]

        // If the tap in fact lies inside the image bounds, 
        // perform the appropriate action.
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(imageFrameInSuperview, tapPoint)) {
            // Perhaps call a method here to react to the image tap
            [self reactToImageTap:image];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This way, the above code is only performed if a tap gesture is recognized, your program only reacts to a tap on the scroll view if the tap location falls within an image; otherwise, you can just scroll your `UIScrollView` as usual.

Comment: and where do you let anything through? you catch event ok -- looks good btw :) but then? where do you forward the event

Comment: @Daij-Djan What do you mean let anything through? This specifically handles all *tap* events on the `UIScrollView`. If it's a scroll gesture, `handleTap` isn't called. If it's a tap not within an image, the `if (CGRectContainsPoint...` conditional isn't performed.

Comment: yes but he wants to have taps go through to the views covered by the scrollview and not just handle it all in the recogniser: "the view behind it has some images that the user should be able to tap on."

Comment: @Daij-Djan What my code does is have the `UIScrollView` recognize the tap gestures itself and then in the recognizer's "handleTap:" action, it checks to see whether that tap was within the frame of one of those below images and if so (`if (CGRectContainsPoint(...`) it calls the appropriate method to then handle the "tap" on that image, effectively allowing that tap to "go through" the scrollview appropriately.

Comment: belive me when I say I totally got your code - im just saying that you have manually handle each possible action there... or at least manually forward the action.

Comment: I deleted my answer. this is the way to go IMO. it needs a bit  of work 'forwarding' the events but its cool

Comment: @Daij-Djan Oh OK. I actually really wanted to understand your answer, but I do think there was a little more that needed to be worked out. And yeah, I understand what you mean by "forwarding" events, but I don't really see it that way... It's more like the scrollview's "handling" the event for the image. Or "manually handling" like you said in your second to last comment.

Comment: for anyone googling here, and @LyndseyScott , fortunately it's now **incredibly simpler to do this** ten years later.  It's only a line of code

Answer (score 5):

Here I present my complete solution that:

- Forwards touches directly to views instead of calling a control event.
- User can specify which classes to forward.
- User can specify which views to check if forward is needed.

Here the interface:

```
/**
 * This subclass of UIScrollView allow views in a deeper Z index to react when touched, even if the scrollview instance is in front of them.
 **/
@interface MJForwardingTouchesScrollView : UIScrollView

/**
 * Set of Class objects. The scrollview will events pass through if the initial tap is not over a view of the specified classes.
 **/
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSSet <Class> *forwardsTouchesToClasses;

/**
 * Optional array of underlying views to test touches forward. Default is nil.
 * @discussion By default the scroll view will attempt to forward to views located in the same self.superview.subviews array. However, optionally by providing specific views inside this property, the scroll view subclass will check als among them.
 **/
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray <__kindof UIView*> *underlyingViews;

@end
```

And the Implementation:

```
#import "MJForwardingTouchesScrollView.h"
#import "UIView+Additions.h"

@implementation MJForwardingTouchesScrollView

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        _forwardsTouchesToClasses = [NSSet setWithArray:@[UIControl.class]];
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        _forwardsTouchesToClasses = [NSSet setWithArray:@[UIControl.class]];
    }
    return self;
}

- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    BOOL pointInside = [self mjz_mustCapturePoint:point withEvent:event];

    if (!pointInside)
        return NO;

    return [super pointInside:point withEvent:event];
}

#pragma mark Private Methods

- (BOOL)mjz_mustCapturePoint:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    if (![self mjz_mustCapturePoint:point withEvent:event view:self.superview])
        return NO;

    __block BOOL mustCapturePoint = YES;
    [_underlyingViews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(__kindof UIView * _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
        if (![self mjz_mustCapturePoint:point withEvent:event view:obj])
        {
            mustCapturePoint = NO;
            *stop = YES;
        }
    }];

    return mustCapturePoint;
}

- (BOOL)mjz_mustCapturePoint:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event view:(UIView*)view
{
    CGPoint tapPoint = [self convertPoint:point toView:view];

    __block BOOL mustCapturePoint = YES;
    [view add_enumerateSubviewsPassingTest:^BOOL(UIView * _Nonnull testView) {
        BOOL forwardTouches = [self mjz_forwardTouchesToClass:testView.class];
        return forwardTouches;
    } objects:^(UIView * _Nonnull testView, BOOL * _Nullable stop) {
        CGRect imageFrameInSuperview = [testView.superview convertRect:testView.frame toView:view];

        if (CGRectContainsPoint(imageFrameInSuperview, tapPoint))
        {
            mustCapturePoint = NO;
            *stop = YES;
        }
    }];

    return mustCapturePoint;
}

- (BOOL)mjz_forwardTouchesToClass:(Class)class
{
    while ([class isSubclassOfClass:NSObject.class])
    {
        if ([_forwardsTouchesToClasses containsObject:class])
            return YES;

        class = [class superclass];
    }
    return NO;
}

@end
```

The only extra code used is inside the `UIView+Additions.h` category, which contains the following method:

```
- (void)add_enumerateSubviewsPassingTest:(BOOL (^_Nonnull)(UIView * _Nonnull view))testBlock
                                 objects:(void (^)(id _Nonnull obj, BOOL * _Nullable stop))block
{
    if (!block)
        return;

    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
    [array addObject:self];

    while (array.count > 0)
    {
        UIView *view = [array firstObject];
        [array removeObjectAtIndex:0];

        if (view != self && testBlock(view))
        {
            BOOL stop = NO;
            block(view, &stop);
            if (stop)
                return;
        }

        [array addObjectsFromArray:view.subviews];
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

##### It's extremely simple to do this:

```
class TrickScrollView: UIScrollView {
    
    override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        
        print("point! \(point)")
        
        if point.y < 400 { // example
            print("     .. pass on to whatever is behind")
            return false
        }
        
        // operate normally
        return super.point(inside: point, with: event)
    }
}
```

That's all there is to it.  At the line of code "y < 400" simply use your own logic to decide if you want to pass through, or handle normally.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `UIScrollView` is consuming the event. To pass it through, you would have to disable the user's interaction on it, but it wouldn't scroll then. If you have the touches location however, you can calculate where would that fall on the underlying view, using the `convertPoint:toView:` method, and call a mathod on it by passing on the `CGPoint`. From there, you can calculate which image was tapped.

Comment: ok ... so that would mean to actually calculate the image and call directly its method rather then just pass the events through. but why do the forwarding of events do not just work?

Comment: not true, you don't have to disable interaction. keeping hottest away from the view works fine

Comment: @Daij-Djan what do you mean? Is there a way to both consume the event and forward it down on the responder-chain?